# code documentation with calls traceback (python)

Tags: python, static-analysis, documentation-generation

I am trying to find an automatic documentation tool that tells me what happens (which other functions or classes are called, and when) e.g. when I instantiate a given (python) class, or run one of its methods, in terms of calls traceback (but better rendered than a usual error log)

Ideally without running the code, using static code analysis (e.g. like `pyreverse` https://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#python)

(it doesn't need to be LLM-based)

any idea if such tool exists?

thanks